# Azure Functions - Python int too large to convert to C long (Azure EA API)

Tags: python, sql, azure

I'm running a data ingestion tool that is fetching data from an API. Its returning about 35k objects that are stored in a list, then later uses SQLAlchemy to insert the object into the DB. This runs fine on Linux/Mac, but errors on Windows. I have seem other posts explaining the issue, but I can't find a resolution. Do I need to transform the data from the API to a different data type before I send it to SQL? If so, how and what type?

I am using 64bit python on Azure, using an App service plan with 8gb.

```
18-01-24T19:06:07.066 Exception while executing function: Functions.main. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Repos\azure-python-siteextensions\source_packages\python.3.6.1\tools\Lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py", line 16, in decode
SystemError: <built-in function utf_16_le_decode> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: decoding with 'utf-16le' codec failed (SystemError: <built-in function utf_16_le_decode> returned a result with an error set)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\main\run.py", line 72, in <module>
    result_prox = connection.execute(ins_stmt, usage_data)
  File "D:\home\site\tools\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 948, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "D:\home\site\tools\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "D:\home\site\tools\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "D:\home\site\tools\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "D:\home\site\tools\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1416, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "D:\home\site\tools\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\home\site\tools\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1170, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "D:\home\site\tools\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 504, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.Error'> returned a result with an error set
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario, I was pulling data from the EA billing API and the EA returns a date object a `2017-04-27T23:00:00.00Z` this date with `00:00:00`in the seconds,minutes,and hour field does not comply with the sql data type `datetime`. Switching to `datetime2` resolved the issue.